# EJS unexpected Token "else"

Tags: node.js, syntax-error, ejs

I have a problem with syntax in ejs which isn't obvious to me:

```
<form class="dataForm" action="<%= template.actionPath %>" method="post">
  <% for(var i in template.inputVar) { %>
    <label><%= template.inputVar[i].labelName %></label>
    <br>
    <% if (template.inputVar[i].type == "option") { %>
        <select name="<%= template.inputVar[i].name %>">
        for(var j in template.inputVar[i].options) { %>
          <option value="<%= template.inputVar[i].options[j] %>"><%= template.inputVar[i].options[j] %></option>
        <% } %>
        </select>
    <% } else { %>
        <input type="<%= template.inputVar[i].type %>" name="<%= template.inputVar[i].name %>">
    <% } %>
    <br><br>
  <% } %>
```

I am rendering a webpage where a form is created. Now I want to add a feature that allowes me to have selections in my form.
Unfortunately ejs does not like my the "else" it says:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token else in C:\Users\etc... while compiling ejs
```

I did some research about this issue but I could not find something that might help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` line is missing the opening ejs script tag

```
for(var j in template.inputVar[i].options) { %>
```

to

```
<% for(var j in template.inputVar[i].options) { %>
```

Also, you should close your form tag

Comment: Damn it! Thank you. Sometimes I am blind to the most obvious mistakes.